# Find two variable function from its relative derivative data points numerically

Tags: numerical-methods

Please help me solve this problem numerically:

At discrete points of the unknown function $z = f (x, y)$, only its relative derivative information is available in the following table. Suggest a numerical method to calculate  $f(x_i,y_i)$ ($0\leq i\leq n$).

**Table of data points:**

[image]

Comment: first thought: Euler's method? You know the derivative at each given point, so you can extrapolate from that ...

Comment: You need the value of $f$ at a point to start the process.

Comment: @MattiP. Could you explain how I can use Euler's method for this problem?

Comment: @user10354138 Okay. Suppose for example f(x,y) = sinx * cosy and we know f(0,0) value at first.